# Can I ask a question about bicycle culture in the Southwest?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am an avid bicyclist who is new to the Texas/Southwestern United States area. I am wondering if its okay to ask questions about bicycle culture in this forum?

I have tried to do so in the travel stack exchange forum, but I find that bicycle culture seems to be as heated as politics for some reason.

At the end of the day, I am just looking for a bicycle community in the Southwest similar to what you see in Philadelphia and Seattle and if anyone can help me figure out whether it is okay to ask it here, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well its certainly on-topic as far as cycling content, but its also highly location-specific.

Assuming Southwest means nevada, arizona, utah, new mexico, etc, then my perception as an overseas foreigner is they're all highly car-focused societies.  California's the odd one out because of the anti-pollution focus of local/state laws, which in theory should boost cycling.

tl:dr go on, ask.  The worst case is no useful answers are forthcoming.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is suitable for Stack Exchange at all.

- It's too broad: Arizona, Colorado, Nevada, New Mexico and Utah between them cover an area about half the size of the European Union; add California and it gets another 20% bigger.
- What is or is not a "bicycle community... similar to what you see in Philadelphia and Seattle" is purely a matter of opinion.  As such, it's likely to generate discussion and argument.
- It's inviting [lists rather than answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/).

Comment: Agree with the issue of what a 'bicycle community' actually is. Without a definition there can't be objective answers. OP may have better luck looking for published statistics on bicycle usage in different metro areas.